# F#: Synchronously start Async within a SynchronizationContext

Tags: asynchronous, f#

[Async.SwitchSynchronizationContext](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-control-fsharpasync.html#SwitchToContext) allows an `Async` action to switch to running within a given `SynchronizationContext`. I would like to *synchronously* begin an `Async` computation within a `SynchronizationContext`, rather than switching inside the `Async`.

This would ensure that `Async` actions are run in the desired order, and that they are not run concurrently.

Is this possible? The documentation for `Async.SwitchSynchronizationContext` mentions using `SynchronizationContext.Post`, but no such functionality is exposed for `Async`.

Comment: `SynchronizationContext.Send` is the synchronous counterpart of `Post`. So you're looking for a way to invoke `Send` with an `Async`? I think a concrete example or even some psuedo-code would make it easier to understand exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested this, but I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to combine the `SynchronizationContext.Send` method (mentioned in the comments) with the `Async.StartImmediate` operation. The former lets you start some work synchronously in the synchronization context. The latter lets you start an async workflow in the current context.

If you combine the two, you can define a helper that starts a function in a given synchronization context and, in this function, immediately starts an async workflow:

```
let startInContext (sync:SynchronizationContext) work = 
  SynchronizationContext.Current.Send((fun _ -> 
    Async.StartImmediate(work)), null)
```

For example:

```
async { 
  printfn "Running on the given sync context"
  do! Async.Sleep(1000)
  printfn "Should be back on the original sync context" }
|> startInContext SynchronizationContext.Current
```

Comment: Thanks. That is exactly what I was looking for.